# T-test for seemingly unrelated regression

Tags: r, regression

I want to compare across two regressions if the coefficients are equivalent using a t-test, how could I approach this and is there a function in R, which does this for seemingly unrelated regressions? The linearhypothesis function only supports chi square and f-tests.

```
structure(list(Mkt.RF = c(-3.58, -2.06, 2.13, 4.26, 3.45, -0.74, 
0.66, -5.11, -5.98, -4.32, 2.3, -3.91, 4.66, -1.52, 3.27, 3.09, 
2.31, 2.93, 4.39, 1.91), SMB = c(3.4, -0.72, 0.27, -1.6, -1.07, 
0.55, -0.76, 0.06, 0.08, -2.52, 0.4, -0.93, 4.36, 0.7, 0.63, 
-0.59, 2.24, -0.24, 0.47, 1.19), HML = c(2.78, -0.73, -0.47, 
-1.51, -2.05, 0.01, 0.38, -0.45, 0.88, -1.83, -2.9, -1.71, 4.23, 
0.28, -0.92, 1.46, -0.35, 0.5, 3.12, 0.29), RF = c(0.27, 0.24, 
0.23, 0.25, 0.26, 0.24, 0.3, 0.25, 0.26, 0.29, 0.28, 0.24, 0.28, 
0.12, 0.09, 0.08, 0.11, 0.03, 0.07, 0.04), Mom = c(-3.05, 0.31, 
-0.18, 0.96, 0.44, 0.77, -0.07, 0.49, 0.62, 1.94, 1.24, 7.79, 
-7.63, 3.75, -1.85, 1.85, -1.82, -0.87, -3.62, 0.28), ST_Rev = c(3.64, 
-0.12, 1.08, -0.54, 0.2, -0.83, 0.59, 0.38, -4.04, -3.54, -0.16, 
-1.2, 5.46, 1.79, 1.15, -0.44, 1.19, 1.96, 2.7, 1.71), LT_Rev = c(4.96, 
1.11, -0.63, -1.9, -2.06, -1.56, -0.56, 2.1, 2.47, -0.14, -0.82, 
1.66, 2.5, 0.82, -0.69, 1.13, 0.29, -0.68, -2.12, 0.65), SMALL.LoBM = c(-0.2503, 
2.9079, -2.7574, 0.0526, 6.5715, -2.9304, 10.823, -3.7417, -8.4998, 
-9.134, 2.3031, -10.7934, 22.6559, -8.0991, 0.0122, 3.9872, 8.0196, 
2.8676, 0.9155, 3.6121), ME1.BM2 = c(1.1499, -2.684, 0.4626, 
0.712, -0.3634, 1.7096, -3.2747, -3.2251, -2.4005, -10.0789, 
-2.5086, -5.2028, 9.4805, 0.5592, 5.8376, 5.6991, 4.7564, 1.8046, 
7.0892, -0.4536), ME1.BM3 = c(0.3391, -2.9947, 3.0314, 2.66, 
-2.005, -0.6318, 0.0214, -3.7985, -4.0396, -6.2716, 0.7112, -4.4564, 
9.2809, -1.7363, 4.1581, 2.3189, 4.1872, 1.2225, 7.3031, 3.1771
), ME1.BM4 = c(2.3947, -2.7768, 2.5032, 1.8131, 0.6916, 1.0397, 
-0.0338, -4.9373, -4.2979, -6.7299, 0.7121, -6.0009, 11.4808, 
-1.4308, 4.6421, 3.3693, 3.8889, 3.225, 6.2092, 2.8972), SMALL.HiBM = c(3.0661, 
-1.9227, 0.616, 2.8892, -0.1074, 1.5065, -0.1177, -4.2014, -4.7744, 
-9.7825, 1.1377, -5.4893, 14.1829, -0.9943, 2.7984, 3.6832, 3.9037, 
3.247, 5.5628, 4.5524), ME2.BM1 = c(1.7551, -5.7328, 2.3007, 
2.2013, 3.297, -0.3559, -1.8405, -4.774, -6.8747, -6.8879, 1.458, 
-5.9069, 12.2022, 0.5558, 8.1202, 4.8782, 4.2682, 0.2252, 2.1459, 
3.9586), ME2.BM2 = c(-0.9705, -1.8677, 0.7317, -1.0295, 4.1267, 
-0.7306, 0.2541, -3.6977, -4.6924, -6.7164, 2.2514, -3.128, 10.4595, 
-0.0779, 2.3431, 3.8102, 3.3286, 4.95, 2.744, 3.2929), ME2.BM3 = c(1.4035, 
-3.6199, 1.6266, 3.6103, 0.4984, -0.5925, 0.3072, -4.2721, -3.8077, 
-5.3892, 1.0828, -1.5308, 8.6883, -0.6165, 3.1584, 2.746, 2.757, 
2.2907, 5.4909, 2.0368), ME2.BM4 = c(-0.2011, -3.6209, 1.9333, 
0.8332, 0.5706, -2.2377, 0.8313, -5.3742, -4.3962, -6.4608, -1.6069, 
-7.2318, 10.738, -0.1293, 2.7462, 2.1808, 3.6956, 3.4065, 5.033, 
2.1134), ME2.BM5 = c(2.0711, -1.8232, 2.8456, 4.0999, 2.7381, 
1.3955, 0.405, -6.2742, -7.0585, -9.4413, 0.3334, -7.2297, 12.7326, 
0.3038, 3.561, 4.8341, 5.7237, 2.9956, 7.3176, 4.6113), ME3.BM1 = c(-0.1804, 
-2.8882, 1.352, 2.9007, 2.782, 1.1381, 0.4867, -6.2306, -5.7554, 
-7.6683, 3.8579, -4.5266, 7.913, -0.4997, 3.1115, 2.7842, 6.7293, 
2.9003, 2.5795, 4.0556), ME3.BM2 = c(-0.7311, -2.9647, 3.2335, 
1.3674, 1.6556, -2.206, -0.6753, -4.4656, -7.6589, -5.5316, 3.1475, 
-2.6196, 8.4187, -0.1565, 4.58, 0.798, 4.7252, 2.4181, 5.6894, 
3.4092), ME3.BM3 = c(-1.4191, -2.7309, 2.89, 3.2702, 3.0169, 
-2.3016, -0.3286, -5.2077, -4.643, -5.6728, 2.0126, -5.0963, 
10.1059, -0.6968, 3.0432, 1.7961, 3.8527, 2.8335, 6.8058, 3.3262
), ME3.BM4 = c(-0.5254, -2.7913, 1.6405, 1.4421, 1.5075, -0.5878, 
1.1964, -5.8299, -5.3617, -6.2945, 1.7535, -7.0812, 12.6428, 
-0.7669, 3.2638, 0.8487, 4.3544, 1.708, 7.1502, 4.1152), ME3.BM5 = c(1.4049, 
-3.8607, 1.5727, 0.7456, 1.9912, -1.1459, 0.8075, -6.2397, -4.5381, 
-7.5731, 3.4239, -4.1991, 10.9095, 0.1019, 4.1297, 4.7065, 4.3938, 
3.4303, 10.057, 1.8304), ME4.BM1 = c(-1.7133, -1.0446, 2.7137, 
4.259, 2.8387, -1.6461, -0.2418, -7.7127, -5.2005, -6.3393, 3.8992, 
-3.7172, 6.9502, -1.4509, 5.7128, 3.7283, 2.5366, 3.3355, 3.7266, 
3.213), ME4.BM2 = c(-1.2759, -1.3582, 1.2222, 1.8649, 1.9799, 
-2.6201, -0.2497, -5.8088, -5.3128, -2.6377, 3.6378, -2.8932, 
7.9308, -0.6119, 2.7065, 2.58, 2.3185, 1.9882, 3.9238, 1.8505
), ME4.BM3 = c(-1.216, -2.5053, 3.1187, 2.4602, 0.4411, -2.2538, 
-0.0837, -4.3101, -3.3985, -3.3454, 1.5862, -0.8756, 7.309, 0.7886, 
3.2176, 2.0817, 2.7693, 2.8197, 5.6228, 3.8941), ME4.BM4 = c(-2.2442, 
-3.8999, 2.0182, 3.5898, 1.2033, -2.6227, 1.0005, -5.9218, -7.1044, 
-7.2683, 1.3216, -7.3886, 13.209, -1.8963, 1.8581, 3.2885, 3.0029, 
3.0511, 5.3104, 1.8811), ME4.BM5 = c(-1.9603, -2.9296, 1.4486, 
0.1516, 3.6732, 0.0404, 1.0588, -5.8241, -8.7229, -10.6485, -0.906, 
-5.8981, 13.5529, -2.6018, 3.0886, 6.0737, 2.1082, 4.763, 9.537, 
3.8238), BIG.LoBM = c(-5.1549, -1.8637, 2.3957, 5.3741, 4.8306, 
0.1678, 1.2408, -5.6726, -7.1147, -3.9227, 2.5652, -3.8819, 2.6308, 
-2.0986, 3.1063, 2.9589, 1.7297, 2.9227, 5.0309, 1.7733), ME5.BM2 = c(-4.7384, 
-1.4001, 1.9731, 5.4208, 2.9949, -2.0476, 0.8084, -4.9762, -5.2956, 
-3.702, 2.7913, -4.5086, 3.4779, -1.3382, 3.1628, 3.3917, 2.6598, 
3.2409, 2.1203, 0.6962), ME5.BM3 = c(-2.3125, -1.9445, 2.0115, 
2.8931, 2.7253, -0.7017, -0.2, -2.5243, -4.2654, -3.6365, 1.4897, 
-1.76, 5.0131, -0.8321, 3.7127, 3.1274, 1.792, 2.9392, 3.729, 
2.1507), ME5.BM4 = c(-4.6173, -4.2998, 0.8601, 4.602, 2.0774, 
-2.303, 0.7922, -5.4849, -5.6303, -5.7929, 1.7485, -7.3657, 6.9289, 
-3.2758, 2.9054, 2.5705, 3.3908, 2.7507, 5.463, 1.784), BIG.HiBM = c(-0.9533, 
-4.2776, 1.9959, 1.6504, 2.5779, 0.0725, 0.9071, -5.1901, -8.6878, 
-7.8173, -4.4356, -7.0048, 11.5797, -3.4114, 1.2488, 6.2048, 
3.9438, 3.1976, 7.7579, 2.0333)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Edit: I added the data frame now

Comment: Please add more information on your problem, what are your two regressions (type of model, variables, what code you use to generate them...)? What do you mean by "if the coefficients are equivalent"? Is it checking if the confidence intervals from both don't  overlap?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro  so I have two regressions, where for the first I regress some portfolio 1 on the market return and some smb factor, for the second its some portfolio 2 on the market return and some hml factor. I want to test now if the coefficients on the market return are the sam

Comment: Ok, can you add the data that you are using so we can run code with? copy the output of `dput(your.dataframe)`.

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro I added the data frame

Comment: Lets continue this discussion in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223568/t-test-for-seemingly-unrelated-regression

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro unfortunately I don't have enough reputation on this stack forum for the chat function :/. I use the systemfit function in R to do the SUR

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the information of this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions

I created two arbitrary equations:

```
eq1 = ME1.BM2 ~ Mkt.RF + SMB
eq2 = ME1.BM3 ~ Mkt.RF + HML

mod = summary(systemfit::systemfit(list(eq1, eq2), data=df))
```

Now we calculate the Z statistic presented in that post:

[image]

For that we retrieve the coefficients of `mod` and compute it by hand:

```
coef1 = mod$eq[[1]]$coefficients[3,] #The 3 is for getting the HML coef
coef2 = mod$eq[[2]]$coefficients[3,] #The 3 is for getting the SMB coef

Z = (coef1[1]-coef2[1])/sqrt(coef1[2]^2-coef2[2]^2) #[2] is the estimate, [2] is the sd
```

Then you can compare `Z` with the critical value of a standard normal distribution for the significance value that you want.

I couldn't find a package that performed this test, but i think that this is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is this really a t-test?

Comment: It isn't, so i guess it's not the best answer for your question. But i don't know how to apply a t-test in this situation, if you do, then edit the post with what test statistic you're looking for, if you (like me) don't, then you have firstly a question on statistics. If that's the case, you should go to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and find it there, then come back and ask how to code it. Another perhaps useful link for you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/what-is-the-correct-way-to-test-for-significant-differences-between-coefficients.